# Why is list undefined if I defined it within the <script setup> in my Nuxt 3 Project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt 3 Project and I created an Component which generates an variable amount of elements, for this the element gets handed an array when called.
Within the script setup I define this array as list and i want to use it within the mounted function to map certain data points onto my data.

Here is the component in use where the array is handed to the element, each of those variables (x.data.attr..) is a String.

```
<Menu
  :items="[
    {
      bildURL: x.data.attributes.BildKasten1.data.attributes.url,
      Text: x.data.attributes.TextKasten1,
      KartenTitel: x.data.attributes.KartenTitel1,
    },
    {
      bildURL: x.data.attributes.BildKasten2.data.attributes.url,
      Text: x.data.attributes.TextKasten2,
      KartenTitel: x.data.attributes.KartenTitel2,
    },
  ]"
/>
```

My Setup:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { faThList } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const props = defineProps({
  items: {
    Array,
  },
});

const list = ref(
  props.items.map((item) => {
    return { ...item, open: false };
  }),
);
</script>
```

my normal script tag (deleted the methods since they have nothing to do with this):

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      obj: {},
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(list);
    for (i in list) {
      this.obj[i.KartenTitel] = idx > 0 ? false : true;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Now it doesnt work and the console logs:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: list is not defined
```

The weirdest/most frustrating part is, when I turned it off yesterday it worked. Today it doesnt. I havent done anything inbetween.
How can I get this to work again? Why isnt it working?
Should'nt list be defined since it is defined within the setup?

Comment: You're using a var that is not defined, that's what the error says and it's so. script setup declares a var is available inside setup block and exposed on the instance. It may or may not be available as this.list, this is not documented and shouldn't be relied on. The problem results from a bad practice, <script> are not justified here, also I'd suggest to not use script setup without a good understanding what it does, it causes more problems that it solves

Comment: @EstusFlask this. doesnt work. In my understanding script setup is executed when the page is loading so I put stuff there that should be executed when the page loads.

Comment: <script setup> is sugar syntax for the body of setup() function. It's supposed to replace <script>. And setup function is supposed to replace options api, which is legacy

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [documentation of Vue 3](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#can-i-use-both-apis-in-the-same-component), it is recommended to use composition api inside options api **only with `setup()` option**, like this, **if you already have options API codebase**. (not 2 `<script>`s):

```
<script>
  export default {
    setup() {
      // composition API
    },

    // options API
  }
</script>
```

Otherwise, you should choose only one of them.

In your case, why you just didn't use `onMounted(() => {})` inside `<script setup>`

Comment: if I try to put it into the ' setup() {} ' within the normal script I get the error ' Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: defineProps is not defined '

Comment: You can access props [like this](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#accessing-props).
Also, please read [this documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#composition-api-setup) before using `setup()` option